# PHP MySQL Array Confusion

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am developing a Twitter application.  My keys are stored in the database for the users, so it sends each user their key.  Basicly, user 1 keys is X, and users 2 key is Y, (example, not for me), and you need their keys to send the tweet.

So I am trying to use all the user's keys in the database as an array.  But it is showing up as this Xy, they are being combined and it thinks it is one whole key.

How can I get PHP to know that those are two different keys?

```
require('config.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$oauthtoken2 = $row['oauth_token'];
$oauthsecret2 = $row['oauth_token_secret'];
$oAuthToken = $oauthtoken2;
$oAuthSecret = $oauthsecret2;
echo "$oAuthToken";
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);
}
```

Comment: "So I am trying to use all the user's keys in the database as an array" -- one user -> one key. Store it as a string

Comment: u should start learning PDO if u are just learning PHP it will be better in the long run

Answer (score 0):

it appears to be concatenated because the echo does not include a space, try

```
echo "$oAuthToken\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
require('config.php');
require_once('twitteroauth.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $oauthtoken2 = $row['oauth_token'];
    $oauthsecret2 = $row['oauth_token_secret'];
    $oAuthToken = $oauthtoken2;
    $oAuthSecret = $oauthsecret2;
    //echo "$oAuthToken";
    $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

    // do what ever you need to do here with the $tweet object.

    //unset($tweet); - unset it here, then loop to the next token / secret pair
}
?>
```